# Trying to create a intent in the onPostExecute method of a AsyncTask

Tags: android

I'm using a `AsyncTask` task to load a response from a web server. Depending on what the response is, I would like start a new Activity or display an error message. Right now I'm trying to do this within the `onPostExecute` method of the `AsyncTask` class. I get a *Constructor is undefined* error when I try to create the Intent.

Here is my code:

```
protected void onPostExecute(String result) {  
      // code thate xcicutes after thread
      if ( result.contains("OK"))
        {
            PreSave();

            Intent I;

            if (ChatOrGame==1)
               i = new Intent(cGlobals.mParent );
            else
                i = new Intent(cGlobals.mParent);

            startActivity(i);       
        }
        else
        {
            if (bInternetError==false)
            {
            new AlertDialog.Builder( cGlobals.mParent)
            .setTitle("Log In Error")
            .setMessage( "User name or password" )
            .setNeutralButton("close",new DialogInterface.OnClickListener()
            {
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dlg, int i)
                {

                }} ).show();            

            }
        }
  }
```

Comment: What is `cGlobals.mParent`? A `context`?

Comment: You can get the result in public variable and the use it to handle condition outside Async method ..that is how I handle normally

Comment: Intent "I" and "i" = new Intent

Comment: Did my answer work for you?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to add the `Activity` you want to start to your `Intent`

```
i = new Intent(cGlobals.mParent, NextActivity.class);
```

[Intent](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html) doesn't have a `Constructor` that accepts only a `Context` so you get this error. You need to add the `Activity` to start so the `Intent` knows what to do with the information. This is assuming of course that `cGlobals.mParent` is a `context`, which I believe it is by the way you are using it elsewhere and the name you have given it. And that you meant for `Intent I` to be `Intent i` which I think was a typo or it shouldn't even compile

**Note** As @Trinimon said in a comment, be sure whatever `Activity` you are starting with the `Intent` is defined in the `manifest` or you will have further issues

Comment: Good answer; will remove mine. May be worth to mention, that the activity has to be defined in the Android manifest file.

Comment: Thanks, not the current issue but I edited with your comment, good point